# android getting an error while trying to draw to the canvas

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i  have a class Handler that is used to draw an arraylist of towers in the gameview class

```
   public class Handler {
public static int Scale=50;
 public static ArrayList<Tower> towers=new ArrayList<Tower>();


public static void draw(Canvas c){
for(Tower t:towers){
    t.draw(c);
}
 }


public static void update(){
for(Tower t:towers){
    t.update();
}
 }

      }
```

GameView class that extends surfaceview and implments surfaceholder.callback

```
           public class GameView  extends SurfaceView implements
           SurfaceHolder.Callback {

          public int ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight;

    TouchInput touchinput;
    TableLayout table;

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    //these variables used for adding new tower
    boolean addingnewtower=false;
    Bitmap Tempbitmap;
    public float x,y;
    //////////////////////////////////////
    public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(context.getResources());

    touchinput=new TouchInput(this); 
    Tempbitmap=sprite.bitmap;
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
            setFocusable(true);//
}

    private static final String TAG = GameView.class.getSimpleName();

    private MainThread thread;




    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
//if(!thread.isAlive()){
setOnTouchListener(touchinput);
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
            boolean retry = true;
    thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
try {
    thread.join();
    retry = false;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // try again shutting down the thread
}
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");

    }




    public void Draw(Canvas c) {
Paint paint=new Paint();//paint used to set color,text font,text size...
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setTextSize(paint.getTextSize()*3);
c.drawRect(100,100,200,200,paint);
c.drawText("touch is"  +  x   +  "  "+  y,200,200, paint);

Handler.draw(c);
if(addingnewtower){
    c.drawBitmap(Tempbitmap,x,y, paint);
}

    }  

    public void update(){

Handler.update();
    }
```

class mainthread  which contains the game loop in the method run()

```
   public class MainThread extends Thread {
private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

// Surface holder that can access the physical surface
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
// The actual view that handles inputs
// and draws to the surface
private GameView gameview;

// flag to hold game state 
private boolean running;
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,GameView gameview) {
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gameview = gameview;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing on the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                if(canvas!=null){
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                gameview.Draw(canvas);}
                gameview.update();
            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    } 
}
 }
```

and finally MainActivity that implements ontouchlistesnser

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
             private ImageView tower1,tower2,tower3,tower4,tower5,tower6;
  private TableLayout layout;
   private GameView gameview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//hide the action bar

             getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//make it full screen

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gameview=(GameView) findViewById(R.id.gameview1);
    tower1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tower1);
    layout=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    tower1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    gameview.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    gameview.onpause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gameview.onresume();
}



//this is called whenever an imageview is touched for adding a new tower on the map
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
    int location[]=new int[2];
    tower1.getLocationOnScreen(location);//get the location of imageview with respect to screen since the touch area will be with respect to the view v width and height
    switch(m.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if(v.getId()==tower1.getId()){//if tower1 is touched
        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//make them invisible
        }
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    gameview.handle_imageView_TouchEvent(location,m.getX(),m.getY(),false);//false meaning in touch move

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        gameview.handle_imageView_TouchEvent(location,m.getX(),m.getY(),true);//this will be called only once for adding the new tower 
layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
gameview.addingnewtower=false;
    break;

    }
    return true;

}


  }
```

when this code do is that whenever i touch an imageview and drag it across the sreen,a new object machinegunner which extend tower is added to the arraylist tower in the handler class
but  after few times of adding new machinegunner to arraylist i am getting a error in the draw method of handler

```
 01-20 18:16:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-114
 01-20 18:16:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 01-20 18:16:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1339): at  java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)               
01-20 18:16:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.example.test1.Handler.draw(Handler.java:15)
01-20 18:16:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.example.test1.GameView.Draw(GameView.java:97)
01-20 18:16:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1339):     at com.example.test1.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:44)
```

plz any help?

Comment: What do the lines in the error correspond to in your classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are adding to the ArrayList whilst in the middle of iterating over it in the draw() method. You can't modify a collection whilst iterating over it (other than removing items using the Iterator).

You don't show what the method 'gameview.handle_imageView_TouchEvent()' does, but I think you need to make it add to the ArrayList using the same Handler that does the draw() and update(). The two processes should then queue up on the same thread and not collide.

Comment: Thx very much,I didn't think of that,I added a method in the handler for adding new object and it work fine